# Materialize Date Picker open on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker, material-design

I'm trying to open the date picker of materialize on a click event.
Here is my jsp

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
 <input id="birthdate" type="date" class="datepicker" name="birthdate">
 <label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
</div>

<div id="birthdate-icon" class="cursor-pointer">
    <i class="material-icons">today</i>
</div>
```

For my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 150, 
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        min: new Date(1900,1,1),
        max: true
    });

    initBindings();
});

function initBindings(){
    $('#birthdate-icon').click(function(){
        $('#birthdate').click();
    });
}
```

The problem is that the date picker is not opening when I'm clicking the icon.

Comment: Is the direct click on input field working?

Comment: yes, it is working fine

Comment: Can you register the click event directly in ready function instead of giving call to a initBindings function. Check if this works.

Comment: Had you got any error message in console?

Answer (score 2):

In your script, you have to register click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#birthdate').click(function(){
        $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true,
            selectYears: 150, 
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            min: new Date(1900,1,1),
            max: true
        });
    });

        initBindings();
    });

    function initBindings(){
        $('#birthdate-icon').click(function(){
            $('#birthdate').click();
        });
    }
```

When you click on `birthdate-icon`, it will make a click to `birthdate` and the script for `datepicker` will be called.